# Averages by multiple columns separately

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a collection table1 with the following columns:

```
id (INT)
col1 (VARCHAR)
col2 (VARCHAR)
value (INT)
```

I want to calculate the average *separately* by `col1` and by `col2` to have a response like this:

```
{
    averageByCol1: {col1Value1: 23, col1Value2: 44},
    averageByCol2: {col2Value1: 33, col2Value2: 91}
}
```

Tried to use multiple columns in GROUP BY, but this combines the columns:

```
SELECT
CONCAT(col1, col2, AVG(value))
FROM table1
GROUP BY col1, col2
```

Also tried with subquery but it gives me `Subquery returns more than 1 row` error:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT
    CONCAT(col1, AVG(value))
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY col1) AS col1Averages,
    (SELECT
    CONCAT(col2, AVG(value))
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY col2) AS col2Averages;
```

Using Mysql v5.5.

edit with sample data:

```
id  col1    col2    value
1   v1      b1      34
2   v2      b1      65
3   v1      b1      87
4   v1      b2      78
5   v2      b2      78
6   v1      b2      12
```

Want average of `value` by v1, v2, b1, and b2 independently.

Comment: can you please post sample data too?

Comment: col1 and col2 are varchar how can you take averages of that??

Comment: @nikhilsugandh averages of the value column

Comment: plaese provide sample data

Comment: @Samir edited with sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a UNION for each column you want to calculate an average for

```
SELECT col1 as col_key, avg(value) as average
FROM test
GROUP BY col1
UNION
SELECT col2, avg(value)
FROM test
GROUP BY col2
```

Answer (score 1):

this will work:

```
  select avg(value),col1 from Table1 group by col1
  union all
  select avg(value),col2 from Table1 group by col2
```

sql fiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c1f111/5/0

Answer (score 0):

If you want 2 queries for separate results:

```
SELECT col1, AVG(value) AS average1
from table1
GROUP BY col1
ORDER BY col1
```

and

```
SELECT col2, AVG(value) AS average2
from table1
GROUP BY col2
ORDER BY col2
```